# Fragment layout is not Scrolling completely when keyboard opens

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-scrollview, window-soft-input-mode

I want the layout inside my fragment to scroll completely and place it above the softkeyboard whenever keyboard opens. But the problem is the layout is not even scrolling when i user click on keyboard. It covers up some part of the layout.

I have tried many SO threads already but none of them seems to be working.

Here's the activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.abc.viewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".home.HomeActivity">

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/taskBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_minus10sdp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_5sdp">

            
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar_practice"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp">

            
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

Here's the fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_bg_splash"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_10sdp">
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/previous"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/left"
                android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp" />
        </RelativeLayout>        

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/right" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Manifest:

```
 <activity android:name=".home.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/MaterialThemeHome"></activity>
```

Comment: tried adding in ScrollView attr `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` ?

Comment: @P.Juni tried not working